# Problema con [ngClass] en Angular 10

Tags: angular, angular10

Cordial saludo

Compañeros la siguiente pregunta es acerca de algo relativamente sencillo pero que no esta dando el comportamiento esperado, estoy utilizando ***ngClass*** para mostrar en un botón un efecto de ***loading*** de ***font awesome***, algo sencillo que cambie la propiedad a ***true*** para decir que muestre en el ***ngClass*** el ***loading*** y si no que no muestre la clase de ***loading*** sino otra clase, lo puse en un ***setTimeOut*** para simular el proceso de una petición asíncrona, pero de resto cambia el estado del valor ***boolean*** mas sin embargo no se ve reflejado el estilo en la clase de ***ngClass***.

Código del botón:

```
introducir el código aquí
<button (click)="ejecutar()" class="btn btn-primary" type="button" name="button">
 <i class="fa" [ngClass]="{'fa-save':!loading, 'fa-sync-alt fa-spin':loading}"></i>
  Guardar cambios
</button>
```

Componente ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-clases',
  templateUrl: './clases.component.html'
})
export class ClasesComponent {

  public loading:boolean = false;

  constructor() { }

   ejecutar(){
     this.loading = true;
     setTimeout(() => this.loading = false, 3000);
   }

}
```

Comment: que version de font-awesome estas usando

Comment: "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.14.0",

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En Font Awesome 5 se modifico la forma de declarar las clases, [Upgrading from v4](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/setup/upgrading-from-version-4)

Mantienen compatibilidad con fa, para los iconos existentes pero muchos cambiaron, esos si tienes que migrarlos a su nueva nomenclatura

```
fas fa-sync-alt
```

```
<button (click)="ejecutar()" class="btn btn-primary" type="button" name="button">
    <i class="fas" [ngClass]="{'fa-save':!loading, 'fa-sync-alt fa-spin':loading}"></i>
    Guardar cambios
</button>
```

Comment: amigo sigue sin funcionar, cuando ejecuto el evento click no cambia al loading

Comment: Te dejo un ejemplo donde si funciona, no se cual archivo de el font awesome estes cargando. 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-wsrrgr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: "scripts": [
              "node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/js/all.js"
            ], estoy cargando este

Comment: Ya replique tu estructura y ya vi cual es el problema, cuando jalas el js, te reemplaza el icono por un svg, lo que te recomiento es cambiar tu angular para en lugar de jalar el js jales el css

Comment: `
"styles": [
              "src/styles.css",
              "node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css"
            ],
`

Comment: Ahora si funciono correctamente amigo, muchas gracias por el aporte.